# Formula to compare the potential earnings of buying the same stock at different prices

Tags: united-states, stocks, trading, calculation, stock-dividend

If I want to buy an index fund, I could buy it today at the current price, or I could setup a limit order and try to buy it at a lower price.

Obviously it's better to get it at the lower price, but *how much* better, exactly? Waiting introduces the risk that it won't be filled, so I'd like to know how to balance the risk vs reward.

Over a N year period, what is the formula to compare the amount I'd earn if I bought it at the current price, against the amount I'd earn if I took the risk and waited for it to potentially reach the lower point?

How is that affected if the fund offers a dividend?

Comment: Based on comments the subject appears to be a dollar-cost-averaging subject. So decide on a hypothetical overall rate-of-return but also include the regular balance deposits in a compounding curve. Then a first compounding curve runs from a point in time of A from a beginning price of Pa while a second compounding curve runs from a point in time of B from a beginning price of Pb. Then the two compounding curves have different peaks at the same ending time. Different beginning times with different beginning prices are just modeled

Comment: Also, a beginning balance deposit not invested at beginning point-in-time of A is simply a larger investment at beginning point-in-time of B. Most of what is needed for these calculations is a compounding calculator. Well, $1000 buying shares at $30 a share is just a $1000 investment at point-in-time A while $1200 buying shares at $28 a share is just a $1200 investment at point-in-time B. Per-share calculations are not needed with a hypothetical rate-of-return. Per-share calculations would require month-by-month hypothetical portfolio calculations and not compounding curves.

Comment: But say that compounding curve A was given a hypothetical rate-of-return of 4%. Using a per-share calculation and based on a ten-year curve then compounding curve B could be given a hypothetical rate-of-return of 4.67%.

Answer (score 4):

If you think that the stock is, on average, going to go up, then not buying it immediately represents a loss of expected value. If you don't think the stock is going up, then you shouldn't buy it at all. Stock prices are a random walk. Buying a stock right after its price goes down has no greater expected return than buying a stock in general.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. For example, let's say `VOO` is at `$230`, and I expect it to go up roughly `7%` over the next 30 years. But, I think there's a 75% chance that it will go down to `$222` in the next month. I could buy it today at `$230`, but I'd get more shares (and therefore earn more interest over 30 years) if I can buy it at `$222`. How can I determine _how much_ more I'd have in 30 years if I buy it at the lower price?

Comment: @IanDunn I think as soon as you start applying a x% chance that a stock moves the way you anticipate, you are treading very seriously into taking more risk than you realize. I will write an answer that describes what you are asking, but consider that what Acccumulation has written here is probably the most valuable way you could have it answered.

Comment: I typically take a very conservative approach, and invest a chunk of my paycheck in index funds each month, regardless of the price, and am planning to hold those for 30+ years. I'm not trying to become a day-trader, but it also seems prudent to take advantage of the current pullbacks and make some extra investments by averaging-in. I'm trying to understand how to do that in a way that's safe, and balances risk vs reward.

Comment: @IanDunn "How to do that in a way that's safe" - Don't invest any cash that you need on a short term basis. For example, even if you believe we are at a market low, you face increased personal risk if you leave yourself insufficient cash to last an emergency, such as temporary job loss, injury, or other large expense.

Comment: I'm frustrated, because I feel like y'all are making a lot of inaccurate assumptions, and not answering the actual question. I'm very frugal, and have been saving a large percentage of my income since I started working. My emergency fund can cover 10 months of regular expenses, and over a year if I made cuts to my budget (which I would). I have additional savings for other unexpected not-quite-emergencies. I'm not putting my life savings into day-trading, I just want to invest _more_ right now at the best _safe_ price, *on top of* the amount I invest every month at the market price.

Answer (score 2):

### What is the formula to compare the amount I'd earn if I bought it at the current price, against the amount I'd earn if I took the risk and waited for it to potentially reach the lower point?

X = current price of the fund

Y = possible lower price of fund at a later date

Z = assumed higher price (than X or Y) at an even later date

If you buy now, your profit will be (Z - X)

If you wait to buy and you are fortunate enough to buy later at a lower price,  your profit will be (Z - Y)

### How is that affected if the fund offers a dividend?

If a security pays a dividend, share price is reduced by the exact amount of the dividend on the ex-dividend date.  Someone usually shows up to rebut this statement.  Should that occur, rather than argue the point, let me state in advance that FINRA rule 5330 **Adjustment of Orders** (USA).  It applies to how open orders to buy or sell the security are handled:

- (a) A member holding an open order from a customer or another broker-dealer shall, prior to executing or permitting the order to be executed, reduce, increase, or adjust the price and/or number of shares of such order by an amount equal to the dividend, payment, or distribution on the day that the security is quoted ex-dividend, ex-rights, ex-distribution, or ex-interest, except where a cash dividend or distribution is less than one cent ($0.01), as follows:
- (1) Cash Dividends: Unless marked "Do Not Reduce," open order prices shall be first reduced by the dollar amount of the dividend, and the resulting price will then be rounded down to the next lower minimum quotation variation.

What does that mean to you?  If you buy XYZ at the close today and it goes ex-dividend tomorrow then in the morning before trading resumes, your stock will be worth $99 and you will be entitled to $1 per share on the Pay Date.  Ignoring the tax inefficiency of receiving the dividend in a non sheltered account, you are effectively buying XYZ for $99. If you understand this then you can factor it into your "Buy" equation.

Comment: Er, I'm sorry, I think I left out an important part of the question. I'd like to calculate this over a long term, so the formula needs to account for earned interest and dividends over a given time horizon ([example](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/121478/formula-to-compare-the-potential-earnings-of-buying-the-same-stock-at-different#comment239801_121486)).

Comment: Just add the dividends and/or interest to the equation.  If you want to determine annual yield, divide by cost basis and then the number of days held and multiply by 365.

Comment: So, for the current price, would that be: `( Z - X ) * {number of shares}` ? And then for the lower price, you'd do the same with `Y`, and then compare the two results? I just did that w/ the example I linked above, and came out with only a `$400` difference for `50` shares, over `30` years. I must be doing something wrong. Do I need to also factor in compounding interest?

Comment: If this involves multiple fund purchases with reinvestment of dividends and you want to determine CAGR then it's a very complicated spreadsheet calculation whose explanation is far beyond the space in these brief comments. If you just want to determine the yield of the entire position then it's (Total Sale price of the entire position at some future date + Dividends - Total Cost of the position). Total cost of the position is an unknown variable at this time because you are contermplating whether to buy now or hopefully at a lower price at a lower date. There is no compound interest involved..

Comment: Your profit will be Z-Y if you buy the same number of shares, but you can buy more shares at the price Y. (You can also buy less shares at the higher price W which it might be on the day when you think it will be Y)

Answer (score 1):

**The concept you are referring to is "expected value"**. Expected value is a concept in probability that says if you know how likely each scenario would be, and the value of that scenario, you can create a sort of 'weighted average' value.

For example: assume I offer you a bet: you pay me $1, and I will flip a coin. If it is heads, I pay you $2. If it is tails, I pay you nothing. This is a simplistic bet, and the intuitive value of it is that, on average if you did this 100 times, then half the time you would get back nothing, half the time you would get back $2, and therefore over 100 times you would get back an average of $100.

In probability-speak, we could say this bet has an Expected Return of $1. That is - on average, performing the bet is worth $1, meaning I have fairly priced your options. Mathematically we can work this out as: 50% chance of $0 + 50% chance of $2 = $1.

Now let's complicate things. Assume I offer you a bet about the weather tomorrow, and you have to pay me $100 if you want to participate. If it rains, I pay you $500. If it doesn't rain, you get nothing. If it snows, I pay you a jackpot of $10,000. How can you find the appropriate Expected Return? If the weather channel was accurate, you could go on, and see that there is, say, a 30% chance of rain tomorrow. So you do the math, and 30% chance of rain adds .3*500 = $150 value + 69.9% chance of no precipitation adds .699 * 0 = $0 value + .1% chance of snow adds .001 * 10,000 = $10 in value = total value of the bet of $160 to you. Great! It only costs you $100 to enter, but the value of the bet is $160!!

**But how certain are you of those %'s?** What if I have a doppler radar system and a meteorological degree, and I estimate that there's only a 5% chance of rain tomorrow? Suddenly the bet is biased towards me. **This is your risk if you try to estimate these values on your own**.

Look up the Random Walk theory of the stock market, as Acccumulation indicated, which basically says that the market is perfectly efficient given all publicly available information, and that movement after that point is effectively random from a perspective of being able to forecast it. Be very, very careful that you don't become overconfident in your abilities. I will kindly point out that if you are asking how to calculate an expected value of a future event, you are not sufficiently informed to be able to invest in individual stocks without getting taken advantage of. I highly recommend you consider yourself a beginner investor, and search for questions on this site for 'how to get started in investing'. The most common advice would be - invest money every paycheck into diversified index funds (equities and fixed income) with low management fees.

Comment: I do consider myself a beginner, and already invest every paycheck into a mix of large-, medium-, and small-cap Vanguard index funds, which I plan to hold for 30+ years. ...but the market is also down 25% in 3 weeks, after skyrocketing for years. I'm getting advice from a trusted friend who's been investing very successfully for 30+ years, and she's advising me to take some extra money, and average-in during this pullback.

Answer (score -2):

Based on prior market close, the S&P 500 can be bought in the current mini futures contract at 2740.25 or bought in the Dec contract at 2701.25.

The Dec contract misses 2.29% in dividends. So 2701.25 plus 2.29% in dividends equals to 2763.11 cost for the Dec contract.

Or the Dec S&P 500 commodity call-option is priced at 296, but actually times 100 total cost, for a contract size of 270000. Scale down to a contract size of 2700 and the cost of the option is 296. Add 296 to 2700 and the total cost is 2996. The price of the option certainly includes a time value but the price is not expected to be adjusted for dividends.

One note with the option example is that it represents a partial loan of the total securities purchase price. So the option price could be recalculated for different interest rates. The calculation is known as a Black-Scholes calculation.

Also, the current S&P 500 commodity call-option, and at the current prior-close price level, is scaled at 2740 + 109 or 2849. That result is for a March 20, 2020 expiration. Ten days costs 109 extra and so obviously there is a volatility risk.

Then a determination of a volatility risk, as in dollar and time amounts, may be the best answer to the question with some of the other points as possible practices within the range of the subject.